# How to change locale in a Struts action class?

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, locale

I have an Action class, and I want to get the locale of my app and change it here, but I don't know how and can't find an answer.

I can get the current locale using `super.getLocale().toString();`

But how to **set locale** I don't know.

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String language;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String result = Factory.INSTANCE.getUserDao().checkUser(login, password);
        if(result == null){
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        if(login.isEmpty() | password.isEmpty()){
            addActionError(getText("login.error"));
        }else {
            addActionMessage(getText("login.correct"));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the locale for my app right in the above Action class. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to see this one: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/i18n-interceptor.html. It says "attributeName (optional) - the name of the session key to store the selected locale. By default this is WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE". It seems that it should be fine to set this session attribute to your new locale. (I've never used Struts2 though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale)` and to put it in HTTP session
`session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale)`.