# How to set locale dinamically via code in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, locale, actioncontext

In my application, I have to display the content based on the locale that an user has chosen in the configuration page. I am not using a browser default locale.

when using `<s:text>`, it always use the default resource file.

In Struts1, I have used the below code to set default locale in my filter

```
session.setAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE",locale);
```

How to set the user chosen locale dynamically in Struts2 ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15582074/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12891293/1700321.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me :

```
String language = userLocale.substring(0, 2);
String country = userLocale.substring(3, 5);
Locale locale = new Locale(language, country);
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale);
session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
```

where the values of `userLocale` are of the form : fr_FR and the file for the resources is named resource_fr_FR.properties

Comment: This works for me but this locale is not changing when I do a another request with request_locale parameter

Comment: maybe if you'd upload the essential configuration and code somewhere I could take a look

Comment: actually that was mine code mistake..... I got it later...nothing wrong with ans...thanks a lot...

Comment: Man, you make my day!!! Thank you for `I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE`. Works as charm!

Answer (score 0):

You set the locale in the following way in Struts 2:

```
ActionContext ctx = ActionContext.getContext();
if (ctx != null)
{
    ctx.setLocale(locale);
}
```

You can also use the [`I18nInterceptor`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/I18nInterceptor.html).

Comment: Why the context is null?

Comment: It can be null in exceptional circumstances but it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

The Struts2 internationalization interceptor [`i18n`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/i18n-interceptor.html) could be used to dynamically change the current user locale to the user specific locale for the user's session.

> "Or, alternatively, only for the current request (since XWork 2.1.3)"

by making an HTTP request and supplying a request parameter `request_locale` with the value of the locale like `"en_US"` which create a locale for English, US.

This locale is saved in the session by default under `"WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE"` attribute and used as a current locale during the user session. The current locale is also pushed into the `ActionContext` map by this interceptor upon every request. This allows framework components that support localization all utilize the `ActionContext`'s locale.

More detailed description with example code you could find in the docs for [I18n Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/i18n-interceptor.html).

> An interceptor that handles setting the locale specified in a session
>   as the locale for the current action request. In addition, this
>   interceptor will look for a specific HTTP request parameter and set
>   the locale to whatever value is provided. This means that this
>   interceptor can be used to allow for your application to dynamically
>   change the locale for the user's session or, alternatively, only for
>   the current request (since XWork 2.1.3). This is very useful for
>   applications that require multi-lingual support and want the user to
>   be able to set his or her language preference at any point. The locale
>   parameter is removed during the execution of this interceptor,
>   ensuring that properties aren't set on an action (such as
>   `request_locale`) that have no typical corresponding setter in your
>   action.
>
> For example, using the default parameter name, a request to
>   `foo.action?request_locale=en_US`, then the locale for US English is
>   saved in the user's session and will be used for all future requests.
>   If there is no locale set (for example with the first visit), the
>   interceptor uses the browser locale.

---